# Highcharts freeze under mobile Safari on iOS 6

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Highcharts can freeze Safari completely on iOS 6 when a tooltip is displayed.
My application display several column charts on a single page and multiple tooltips may be shown at the same time. At some point when the user clicks on a column (with the intention to see a tooltip for this column) Safari freezes completely and must be killed.

The problem seems to occur when a tooltip is displayed in one chart and the user clicks on a column in a different chart. It can also occur when the user clicks on a different column in the same chart.

Additional notes:

- The charts use categories instead of a timeline
- Each charts display 4-5 columns
- The problem occurs even if only two charts are displayed
- The charts are working properly on Desktop (Google Chrome, Firefox)
- Highcharts version is v2.3.5

There seems to be a similar problem described here:
http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=24968#p92497

However, the proposed solution does not work for me since my application does not use "minRange" (formerly "maxZoom") nor "minRange"/"maxZoom" is set explicitly to any constant in Highcharts' source code.

I suppose that Safari freezes because of high CPU usage. However, I know of no way to test that. I do not have a Mac to test on a simulator or debug on iOS.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. For multiple line series however. I can reproduce the problem with the Highstock demos on their website.